# When removing items from a combobox the last item is removed but the text remains... how do I make the combobox blank after last item is removed?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Really simple question but just can't find an answer anywhere.

I've created a command button that removes items from a list in a combobox based on which item they have selected. When the last item is removed, it "technically" is removed but the text for the last item remains in the combobox field. This would confuse the user; in this instance they would believe an item is still attached (the list of items are file pathways.)

I've tried convoluted routes e.g. setting the first index field as "No attachments" and building a solution around this. e.g. when the last field is removed, set it to "no attachments." but this requires me to initialise the combobox this way and change other areas of my code which just unnecessarily complicates it all.

Just a brief description of code, it takes a boolean which the user prompts by choosing either yes to removing all or pressing a remove selected option

```
Private Sub rmvFile(removeAll As Boolean)
    If removeAll = False Then
    'trying to work out how to remove selected item
        fileListComboBox.RemoveItem (fileListComboBox.ListIndex)
    Else
        Do While fileListComboBox.ListCount > 0
            fileListComboBox.RemoveItem (0)
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

The result I would expect is that when I remove the last item in the combobox it would be blank, but this doesn't happen. The last items text remains in the combobox, confusing the user.

Comment: Will `fileListComboBox.Clear` work?

Comment: yep that did the trick. Why was that so hard to find somewhere online :S!

Comment: the .clear only seems to work inside the Do While Loop. If i'm removing a selected item it clears the whole list. Tried using a conditional to say if the listcount is = 0 then .clear, but doesn't seem to clear it...

Comment: Sorry, should have been clear that that will only work if you are clearing everything.  Try setting `fileListComboBox.Value=""` when the count is zero.